# Why am I getting an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when setting the info pointer of a FSFileOperationClientContext?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I am using `FSCopyObjectAsync` to copy files in a Cocoa app. Problem is, whenever I try to set the `info` field (an object of type `void *`) the application crashes because of an `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
// Start the async copy.
FSFileOperationClientContext *clientContext = NULL;
if (spinner != nil) {
    clientContext->info = (__bridge void *)(spinner); // <- Problem here!
}

status = FSCopyObjectAsync(fileOp,
                           &source,
                           &destination, // Full path to destination dir.
                           CFSTR("boot.iso"), // Copy with the name boot.iso.
                           kFSFileOperationDefaultOptions,
                           copyStatusCallback,
                           0.5, // How often to fire our callback.
                           clientContext); // The progress bar that we want to use to update.

CFRelease(fileOp);
```

I'm using ARC, and it works if I comment out the lines dealing with `clientContext` and pass `NULL` in the last argument of `FSCopyObjectAsync`, but that severely cripples my application's functionality. It's definitely the assignment, therefore, that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a NULL pointer without allocating it and then trying to reference it. Change the code so you allocate it on stack and pass its address like below.

```
    // Start the async copy.
FSFileOperationClientContext clientContext;
if (spinner != nil) {
    clientContext.info = (__bridge void *)(spinner);
}

status = FSCopyObjectAsync(fileOp,
                           &source,
                           &destination, // Full path to destination dir.
                           CFSTR("boot.iso"), // Copy with the name boot.iso.
                           kFSFileOperationDefaultOptions,
                           copyStatusCallback,
                           0.5, // How often to fire our callback.
                           &clientContext); // The progress bar that we want to use to update.

CFRelease(fileOp);
```

Comment: Fails with the error `error: address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file`.

Comment: Different issue, hard to tell without seeing the complete code. Have you looked at the various example code that use FSCopyObjectAsync?

Comment: Yeah, but they're not super helpful. I couldn't find any code that is doing what I'm trying to do. The code is open source though on GitHub; here's the link to the file in question: http://bit.ly/ZhzyCG The code in question is a little bit more than halfway down.

Comment: Oh, that makes it easy, I will clone it and see what is going on - I am also a newcomer to Obj-C (more of C/C++/Java guy) so I will refrain from promising anything :)

Comment: Thanks. I'll stay hopeful. :)

Comment: I got it working! I moved `clientContext` to global scope and changed `spinner` to be a `strong` variable. Thanks for the help!